# Add custom toolltip to the Antd datepicker dates

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd date picker in my react application. I want to show a custom message while hovering or clicking on the dates. but it is not working as expected, the tooltip is not showing while hovering over the dates

```
import React from 'react';
import { DatePicker, Space, Tooltip } from 'antd';

const App = () => {
  const renderDatePickerCell = (date) => {
    return <Tooltip title="prompt text">
      <span>{date.date()}</span>
    </Tooltip>
  };
  const onChange = (date, dateString) => {
    console.log(date, dateString);
  };

  return (
    <Space direction="vertical">
      <DatePicker onChange={onChange} cellRender={renderDatePickerCell} />
    </Space>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

To show a tooltip when hovering over the dates, you can't directly use the `Tooltip` component as a child of the `span`. Instead, you should use CSS to apply the tooltip effect.

You can achieve this by defining a CSS class for the tooltip and applying it to your date cells.

```
import React from 'react';
import { DatePicker, Space } from 'antd';
import './App.css'; // Import your CSS file

const App = () => {
  const renderDatePickerCell = (date) => {
    return (
      <span className="custom-tooltip">
        {date.date()}
        <span className="tooltip-text">prompt text</span>
      </span>
    );
  };

  const onChange = (date, dateString) => {
    console.log(date, dateString);
  };

  return (
    <Space direction="vertical">
      <DatePicker onChange={onChange} cellRender={renderDatePickerCell} />
    </Space>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In your CSS file (e.g., `App.css`), you can define the styles for the tooltip effect:

```css
.custom-tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip-text {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 1;
}

.custom-tooltip:hover .tooltip-text {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

This CSS code creates a custom tooltip that is initially hidden (with `visibility: hidden`) and becomes visible when you hover over the date cell.

Comment: when i run this in stack blitz, it is not wokring, https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gqjzkr?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: can you pls share your answer as a runnable code

Answer (score 0):

Following antd custom cell rendering [docs](https://ant.design/components/date-picker#components-date-picker-demo-cell-render) you can show tooltips in every day/date option in picker using `useCallback` hook:

```
const cellRender = React.useCallback((
  current: number | Dayjs, 
  info: CellRenderInfo<Dayjs>
) => {
  if (info.type !== "date") {
    return <Tooltip title="prompt text">{info.originNode}</Tooltip>;
  }

  if (typeof current === "number") {
    return (
      <Tooltip title="prompt text">
        <div className="ant-picker-cell-inner">{current}</div>
      </Tooltip>
    )
  }

  return (
    <Tooltip title="prompt text">
      <div className="ant-picker-cell-inner">{current.date()}</div>
    </Tooltip>
  )
}, [])

...

<DatePicker cellRender={cellRender} />
```

You can find a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/customized-cell-rendering-antd-5-10-1-forked-xv6gxc?file=/demo.tsx:830-868).

OBS: If you don't add `className="ant-picker-cell-inner"` your tooltips will not show.